# How to use the UserID generated by User model generated by Devise gem as foreign key in other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

How establish a connection between the models in the app I am trying to create. Planning to generate a user model using devise gem. Each user will either be a student or patient. So I am planning to create student model and patient model separately. How to link the user model to student model and user model to patient model?

**User Model:** (Created by Devise Gem I guess)

- ID
- UserName
- Password

**Student Model:**

- ID (Foreign key from User model)
- FirstName
- LastName
- StudentID
- Volunteer Hours

**Patient Model:**

- ID (Foreign key from User model)
- Patient Name
- Patient Info

Does my schema makes sense? 
Please advise

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you as well as for future SO searchers.

Answer (score 2):

User Model: (Created by Devise Gem I guess)

```
ID
UserName
Password
FirstName
LastName
StudentID
Volunteer Hours
Info
is_student :boolean, default: false
is_patient :boolean, default: false
```

So, if a user is student then for that `is_student` will be true and for patient `is_patient` will be true

`User.where(is_student: true)` => User who are students

`User.where(is_patient: true)` => User who are patients

`user.is_student?` => true if a user is student

`user.is_patient?` => true if a user is patient

To get Students or Patients in model it can be done by scope also

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :students, -> {where(is_student:true)}
  scope :patients, -> {where(is_patient:true)}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there are actually two parts to your question:

1. How to use the `id` from the `User` model as a foreign key, and
2. Does your schema make sense.

As to #1 (taking `Student` as an example), your `students` table should include a `user_id` field and you should use a `belongs_to` association, something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: students
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id            :integer
#

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

end
```

As to #2, that's hard to say. At first blush, it seems plausible to have separate `Student` and `Patient` models given that there are unique data for each. But, there are multiple ways of approaching the problem and which one makes the most sense is highly dependent on your current and future requirements.

Comment: If I add belongs_to to both Student and Patient model, how will I define the has_one association in User model